# Measure program execution time in nanoseconds

Tags: time, g++, execution

I am trying to measure execution time for my program in the nanosecond in g++ 4.2.2 in visual studio the library #inlcude is not being recognized by the compiler. I am not allowed to compile my program in any other compiler instead g++ 4.2.2

Is there any other options which I can use to measure the starting time and ending time of my program in nanoseconds.

This is what I am doing

`int main(){`

`auto start= chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();`

```
.....my program.....

auto end= chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
cout<<chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(end - start).count();
return 0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

The chrono library is only available starting in c++11. Your compiler may be too old to use chrono.  This link seems to indicate that g++4.3 was the earliest version of g++ to incorporate any c++11 features.

https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx11

You should look at Boost.  It will most likely have something you can use (i.e., boost::posix_time::nanoseconds).

http://www.boost.org/

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html#date_time.posix_time.time_duration